# Count of RichTextEditor > 1 with Lexical

Tags: toolbar, lexicaljs

in the project i have a task dynamicly create components.
Some of them has RichTextEditors inside, but when i create more than 1 components i have one state text inside RichEditor. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2cc5.png)

My init Lexical:

```
        <LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
            <Header />
            <Sidebar />
            <Desktop />
            <Bottombar />
        </LexicalComposer>
```

How can i fix it ?